# Find most and second most popular element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, search

```
var elements = ['1','2','2','2','3','4','3'];
```

I want to find the elements which are the most popular and second most popular in one go.

Here '2' occurs three times and '3' occurs two times.

result would be--

```
popular = ['2', '3']
```

Comment: What have you tried please ... Please be so kind and Read some tutorials on javascript (or whatever you wish to use) and try yourself first, and if you already have then share your efforts with us and ask what exactly is not working ... SO is here to help you get around issues, and not to write your code for you ...

Comment: I am trying from last night but could not get the correct result.

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: We will all be delighted to see what you have tried, what result you are getting, and try to point out what you could do better to achieve your result !!

Comment: In C# this would be something like `elements.GroupBy(item => item).OrderBy(group => group.Count()).Take(2)`

Answer (score 2):

This can be one of the possible solution

```
var elements = ['1','2','2','2','3','4','3']; // input array

// create object with frquency count
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
    if (elements[i] in obj) {
        obj[elements[i]] += 1;
    } else {
        obj[elements[i]] = 1;
    }
}
// map obj to array
var array=[];
for(a in obj){
 array.push([a,obj[a]])
}

// sort the array
array.sort(function(a,b){return a[1] - b[1]});

array.reverse();

// for first two popular elements
var result = [];
result[0] = array[0][0];
result[1] = array[1][0];

console.log(result);
```